# No more CTRL+ALT+DEL?

Tags: windows-10, login

As I understand, CTRL+ALT+DEL was a feature in Windows Pre "10" (Maybe pre 8?) that was used as a security feature.

I notice I can touch any key now in Windows 10 from the image screen (you know, it has date, time and an image) and my logon screen appears.

What happened to CTRL+ALT+DEL?

If it is not needed now, does that mean more secure? Or that it made no difference in Windows 7?

Comment: Nothing your understanding is wrong that shortcut has been around for 2 and half decades

Comment: @Ramhound - I do not understand what you mean. My question was that it seemed like it was not needed, while for decades, I had to do the three buttons. Of coarse I can see now that there is an answer...I guess that is what i was looking for, an answer.

Comment: I just indicated your understanding that the keyboard was something, that was introduced in Windows 8, is not correct.  The Interactive logon, is not something added recently to Windows, it has been around since at least Windows XP.

Comment: I guess what i did not make clear is that I have always used it, and it seemed to not be there in Win 10 or 8. Thanks for your clarity, now I know why you were confused and what you were trying to explain ;)

Comment: If you deal with lots of devices connected to a domain, looks like the default value did change, with Windows 8 though.  So that might be where you got where it was a new feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing has changed.  It is still controlled by the Local Security Policy (Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options):

> **Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL**
>
> This security setting determines whether pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL is required before a user can log on.
>
> If this policy is enabled on a computer, a user is not required to press CTRL+ALT+DEL to log on. Not having to press CTRL+ALT+DEL leaves users susceptible to attacks that attempt to intercept the users' passwords. Requiring CTRL+ALT+DEL before users log on ensures that users are communicating by means of a trusted path when entering their passwords.
>
> If this policy is disabled, any user is required to press CTRL+ALT+DEL before logging on to Windows.
>
> Default on domain-computers: Enabled: At least Windows  8/Disabled: Windows 7 or earlier.
> Default on stand-alone computers: Enabled.

Be careful because the policy is a negative.  Default of "Enabled" means that the user does not need to press Ctrl+Alt+Del... and this has been default for some time.  You can set the policy to "Disabled" and then CTRL+ALT+DEL is required on Windows 10 (I just tested it).